# Pressing a button on a custom keyboard is resulting in "Unrecognized selector being sent to instance error"

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I know there are plenty of other questions addressing the same problem, but since I'm using a custom keyboard, I thought my problem would be slightly different.

This is the specific error:

**-[EquationTextField element1Pressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b68ee0
2012-01-02 12:23:44.630 rowQuiz[20975:207]   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EquationTextField element1Pressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b68ee0'**

I have a view controller, quizController. Inside quizController is a custom view, textField (added through interface builder).

When textField is tapped, another custom view, formulaKeyboard, pops up as its keyboard. When a button on the keyboard is pressed, method `element1Pressed:` is called, and the error described above appears.

Some other questions say that there must be a problem with the retain count, so I tried retaining and releasing quizController in the app delegate, which  didn't solve the problem.

It is also possible that I hooked up something incorrectly in Interface Builder; For the custom keyboard, File's owner and the main view are set to class elementKeyboard. For quizController, File's owner is set to quizController and hooked up to it's view.

Below is the code of the textField's class.

EquationTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FormulaKeyboard.h"


@interface EquationTextField : UIView <KeyInput> {

FormulaKeyboard *keyboard;
NSString *lastElement;
}

@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;

@end
```

EquationTextField.m

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
if (self) {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self addGestureRecognizer:
     [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)]];


   NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id object in bundle) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[FormulaKeyboard class]])
            keyboard = (FormulaKeyboard *)object;
    }   


    self.inputView = keyboard;
    keyboard.delegate = self;

}
return self;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

return YES;
}

#pragma mark -- KeyInput Protocol Methods

- (void)addElement:(NSString *)elementName {


}

- (void)addCharge:(NSString *)chargeIncrease {


}

- (void) addState:(NSString *)stateName {

}

- (void)deleteCharacter {


}


- (void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}
```

formulaKeyboard.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol KeyInput <UITextInputTraits>

- (void) addElement:(NSString*) elementName;
- (void) addCharge:(NSString*) chargeIncrease;
- (void) addState:(NSString*) stateName;
- (void) deleteCharacter;

@end

@interface FormulaKeyboard : UIView {

id <KeyInput> delegate; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <KeyInput> delegate;


-(IBAction) element1Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) element2Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) element3Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) element4Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) element5Pressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) element6Pressed:(id)sender;

-(IBAction) chargePlusPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) chargeMinusPressed:(id)sender;

-(IBAction) solidSatePressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) liquidStatePressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) gasStatePressed:(id)sender;



@end
```

formulaKeyboard.m

```
- (IBAction)element1Pressed:(id)sender {

[delegate addElement:@"Na"];

}

- (void)element2Pressed:(id)sender {

[delegate addElement:@"N"];


}

- (void)element3Pressed:(id)sender {

[delegate addElement:@"O"];


}

- (void)element4Pressed:(id)sender {


}

- (void)element5Pressed:(id)sender {



}

- (void)element6Pressed:(id)sender {


}
```

appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

quizController = [[QuizController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizController" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:quizController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

     - (void)dealloc
{
[_window release];
[quizController release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Is that all of EquationTextField's implementation? Does it have a `element1Pressed:` method?

Comment: @MyztikJenz The `element1Pressed:` method is in FormulaKeyboard's implementation. I added code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of the keyboard's buttons are pointing to the wrong place. You've probably got them wired to File's Owner inside the FormulaKeyboard nib when they should be wired to the FormulaKeyboard object you're creating inside the nib.

`NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];`

That's being called from EquationTextField, so `self` would be your instance of EquationTextField. If you're keyboard's targets are pointing there, that's why you get the unrecognized selector exception.

Comment: "they should be wired to the FormulaKeyboard object you're creating inside the nib." I'm assuming you mean the nib of the viewController. I don't have a FormulaKeyboard object within the nib of the vc, though, because the keyboard appears by itself since  `equationTextfield.inputView = keyboard`

Comment: I tried doing it programmatically, but it gave an error. What I did was add IBOutlets for the buttons of the keyboard inside the keyboard's nib, and then inside equationTextField, put `[keyboard.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(element1Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
`

Comment: and an error came for `NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];`

Comment: In your FormulaKeyboard nib, to which object do you have Touch Down (or Touch Up Inside) connected? You shouldn't have to do this programmatically, although it should work all the same.

Comment: Inside the main rectangle, I added a UIButton which acts as one of the keyboard's keys. At first, I hooked this to the file owner inside the formulaKeyboard nib and added the method `element1Pressed:` which gave me the original error. Then I deleted the connection, hooked up the button to the file owner in the keyboard nib, and made the button an IBOutlet so I could refer to it in code. Then I went to the textField implementation and added what I mentioned a couple of commments ago

Comment: In your FormulaKeyboard nib, drag a connection from the button to the FormulaKeyboard custom view (probably the main view in the nib). Even if File's Owner is set to the FormulaKeyboard class, `loadNibNamed:owner:self:` with a different owner object will override what's defined in the nib. If you want to try this in code again and still have the IBOutlets to the buttons, `[keyboard.button1 addTarget:keyboard action:@selector(element1Pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is a method called `element1Pressed:` is being sent to an instance of `EquationTextField`. You need to actually add the method to the class for it to work. Right now, it's sending the message to the field class, but there's no matching method, so it's throwing an error.

Also, I can't be completely sure about this, since you haven't posted the whole code and/or NIB info, but it seems that you may be going about this the wrong way. You should be using a view controller to handle everything, rather than a custom text field class. I notice that you haven't posted any code for the `QuizController` class. Once you do so, I may be able to give you more advice.

---

**EDIT:** Now that you've posted more code, I think I see the problem. You want the `FormulaKeyboard` instance to receive the event, but the event is linked to the `EquationTextField` instance instead. Make sure you wire it to an instance of `FormulaKeyboard` instead.

On the other hand, it seems that you may not have an instance of `FormulaKeyboard` in the NIB at all. Add an `NSLog` after `keyboard = (FormulaKeyboard *)object` to test if `keyboard` is ever actually assigned a value. If the `NSLog` doesn't fire, double-check that you've actually added an instance of `FormulaKeyboard` to the NIB.

Comment: I added more code. I haven't actually added anything into the view controller yet

Comment: The reason that I'm passing information directly from one view to another is that the textfield and the keyboard communicate through a protocol `<KeyInput>` This protocol is basically a customized version of `<UIKeyInput>` which also passes info directly between a keyboard and another view.